# Subtract each row from first row in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe (called df) with three variables, the head of which shown below. There are 600 rows of data.

```
         X1        X2        X3
0  0.049150  0.270032  0.577858
1  0.602387  0.065492  0.555747
2  0.598355  0.235002  0.482744
3  0.522151  0.253991  0.402630
4  0.402601  0.206630  0.553987
```

I am trying to subtract each row from the first. That is, I'm looking for row1 - row2, then row1 - row3, and so on. I am new to using for loops (and Python in general), and my current attempts aren't getting very far:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    diff[i] = df.iloc[0,:] - df.iloc[i,:]
    diff2 = math.sqrt((diff[0])**2 + (diff[1])**2 + (diff[2])**2)
    print(diff2)
```

for context on the final three lines, I am trying to take the square root of the differences between each row item. So,

```
sqrt((row1col1-row2col1)^2 + (row1col2 - row2col2)^2 + (row1col3 - row2col3)^2)
```

and then I want to store the results of this for all the row differences up to row 600 in a new vector.

If you would like further context, I am trying to implement the second step of a "Subtractive Clustering" algorithm, the formula for which is as follows:

[image: formula]

where ra=1

Comment: Pretty sure you can (and should) do all that without any explicit loops. Not versed enough in pandas to tell you how off the top of my head.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First row can be accessed with [iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) like this:

```
row1 = df.iloc[0]
```

And then we can use apply on row 1 to end:

```
df.iloc[1:].apply(lambda x: np.sqrt(sum((row1-x)**2)), axis=1).values
```

Returns:

```
array([ 0.59025138,  0.55848   ,  0.5046703 ,  0.35988505])
```

Comment: `df.iloc[0]` is a better way to get the first row of a dataframe, because it gets the first row by position. By contrast, `df.loc[0]` gets the row with an index of 0, which happens to be the first row in the question, but it won't work in general.